# Making a object bounce

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to make a elipse bounce on a rectangle. I am using a timer to move the elipse in both x and y-direction. My idea was to create an if statement to see if the coordinates of the elipse matches the coordinates of the rectangle.

Here is the code I had written so far:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {      
    Class1 square = new Class1();
    public int before;
    public int after;
    public int c;

    public Form1()
    {      
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        after = 590 - (b * b) / 100;
        before = 100 + (a * a) / 100;
        c = a + b;
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        SolidBrush Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        g.FillEllipse(Brush, a, before, 10, 10);            
        square.Draw(g);


        if (k >= square.y && a >= square.x && a <= square.x + 40)
        {
            a=c;
            before= after;
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Stop();
        }
        else if (k >= square.y + 10)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("You lost");                
        }          
    }        

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        square.x = e.X;         
        Cursor.Hide();
    }

    public int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;

    public void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a += 1;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b += 1;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I know that there are problems. And I have some questions:

1. Is there a easier way to make the elipse " bounce"?
2. Is the problem solely with the maths of the curve that the elipse is following?

I know the question may be somewhat undefined or abstract but any help is appriciated. And if you want me to be clearer in some ways, let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to make the ellipse bounce of the edges is to check its edge points against the bounds, and then just invert the proper direction. So, something like this should work, if you'll pardon the pseudo-code

```
loop used to animate the ellipse
before moving, check the position:

if right-most position == right wall
    invert x velocity
if left-most position == left wall
    invert x velocity
if top-most position == top wall
    invert y velocity
if bottom-most position == bottom wall
    invert y velocity

move ellipse to next position
```

This is a pretty simple simulation, but it should give you an idea of how to progress and develop a more sophisticated model. Hope this helps!